# Copy FBO to file

Tags: opengl

I been trying to copy my FBO to file

My FBO looks like this:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorAttachment0, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthAttachment);
```

and my copy to file code looks like this:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
unsigned char* pixels3 = new unsigned char[(int)WIDTH * (int)HEIGHT * 4];
glReadPixels(0, 0, 800, 800, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels3);
stbi_write_png("capture3.png", WIDTH, HEIGHT, 4, pixels3, WIDTH * 4);
```

But the image it write out is always black.

Comment: First of all, does the read-back succeed without errors?  Have you checked whether there are non-zero values in `pixels3` after read-back? Can you confirm there are actually non-zero values in the color attachment, i.e. if you blit the FBO to the default framebuffer or render a primitive with the color attachment mapped to it, do you see something on screen? Does the write to PNG succeed without errors?

Comment: Another option is to read directly from the RT texture with [glGetTexImage](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml)